# Why does using an "_ " in variable name disable calc function?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have this very simple calculator:

```
<!-- calculator -->             
<script type='text/javascript' >
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
  one = document.DINNERForm.firstBox.value;
  document.DINNERForm.chargetotal.value = ((one * 1) * (250 *    1)).toFixed(2);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>



<input class="right" type=text name="firstBox" value=""   onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
* 250.00<br>
= <input class="right" type=text name="chargetotal">    
</FORM>
```

This works fine.

BUT, I have to change the name "chargetotal" to "charge_total", as that is the variable that I have to submit to a hosted payment page.

PROBLEM, when I change the name to "charge_total", the calculator no longer works:

```
<!-- calculator -->             
<script type='text/javascript' >
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
 one = document.DINNERForm.firstBox.value;
  document.DINNERForm.charge_total.value = ((one * 1) * (250 *  1)).toFixed(2);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>



<input class="right" type=text name="firstBox" value=""  onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
* 250.00<br>
= <input class="right" type=text name="charge_total">    
</FORM>
```

Can anybody help me with a solution to having a simple calculator that outputs to "charge_total"?

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ebnwLeq9/

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of using an interval function, use `onkeyup="calc()"`

Comment: At what point is it not working the above code seems to work to update the input.  Are you having trouble when submitting the form to the payment site?

Comment: @Barmar - thanks very much for your prompt replies - thanks to you I have found and solved the problem.

Comment: @SkipHoward Please put the solution as an answer to your own question so others who find this question in the future can know what to do.